# When the synchronous_commit parameter is used in standalone and primary/standby modes, are the meanings of the values local and on different?

Tags: open-gauss

When the GUC parameter synchronous_commit of the openGauss database is used in standalone and primary/standby modes, are the meanings of the values local and on different?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, about openGauss  the meanings of the values local and on are different when the synchronous_commit parameter is used in standalone and primary/standby modes. In standalone mode, the local value means that the transaction is committed locally, while the on value means that the transaction is committed on the primary server. In primary/standby mode, the local value means that the transaction is committed on the primary server, while the on value means that the transaction is committed on both the primary and standby servers.